# EMR cluster not terminating on failure from stepfunction

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, aws-step-functions

We are creating EMR cluster from stepfunction.Below are steps it performs

1. Create Cluster
2. preprocessing (like installing scripts etc)
3. submit job
4. terminate cluster

Issue here is when the #3 step fails (submit job) it does not terminate the cluster when job fails.
When job success it terminates cluster. Below is definition of step (Ignore syntax)

```
"Submit_Job": {
        "Type": "Task",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::elasticmapreduce:addStep.sync"
        "Parameters": {
            "ClusterId.$": "$.FormattedInputsForEmr.ClusterId",
            "Step": {
                "Name": "Start Job",
                "ActionOnFailure": "CONTINUE",
                "HadoopJarStep": {
                    "Jar": "command-runner.jar",
                    "Args.$": "$.FormattedInputsForEmr.Args[*][*]"
                }
            }
        }
```

Now when i try ActionOnFailure=TERMINATE_CLUSTER it gives me below error

`Action on Failure 'TERMINATE_CLUSTER' is invalid Status Code: 400  ErrorCode: ValidationException`

What i am missing here

Comment: What are  you using to sumit step, boto3? cant find exact documentation for `Submit_Job`

Comment: @A.B Submit_Job is just a name.

Comment: Can you verify if your termination protection is enabled from console, like i mentioned in my asnwer

Answer (score 1):

If your cluster is created and terminated in the State Machine itself, there is another way to achieve this by using [Step functions Error Handling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-error-handling.html) to catch the Error and divert to the terminate step.

For e.g.,

```
"Submit_Job": {
  "Type": "Task",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::elasticmapreduce:addStep.sync",
  "Parameters": {
    "ClusterId.$": "$.FormattedInputsForEmr.ClusterId",
    "Step": {
      "Name": "Start Job",
      "ActionOnFailure": "CONTINUE",
      "HadoopJarStep": {
        "Jar": "command-runner.jar",
        "Args.$": "$.FormattedInputsForEmr.Args[*][*]"
      }
    },
    "Catch": [
      {
        "ErrorEquals": [
          "States.ALL"
        ],
        "Next": "<Terminate-Cluster-State>"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but I found out that I created my EMR with step concurrency. See the
[screenshot of EMR step tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tJZH.png).

Apparently you must add EMR steps with `actionOnFailure = CONTINUE` for EMR with step concurrency greater than 1.

See the AWS documentation on this: [Considerations for running multiple steps in parallel](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-concurrent-steps.html)